# Angularjs ng-repeat over an array in objects

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to itterate through elements which are in array which is in object using ng-repeat.

This is what i have done so far:

Controller:

```
app.controller('videoDisplayCtrl', function($scope){

var videos = 
    [
        {
        title: 'Course introduction',
        pictureUrl: 'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_kNT5UnXz5dQ6tId9YO0wIJ7YSgRvD1SUxyfdXcXZVdOH7z4b',
        length: '3:32',
        category: 'IT',
        subscribers: 3,
        date: new Date(2014, 12, 15),
        haveSubtitles: false,
        comments: [
            {
            username: 'Pesho Peshev',
            content: 'Congratulations Nakov',
            date: new Date(2014, 12, 15, 12, 30, 0),
            likes: 3,
            websiteUrl: 'http://pesho.com/'
            },
            {
            username: 'Pesho Peshev1',
            content: 'Congratulations Nakov',
            date: new Date(2014, 12, 15, 12, 30, 0),
            likes: 3,
            websiteUrl: 'http://pesho.com/'
            },
            {
            username: 'Pesho Peshev2',
            content: 'Congratulations Nakov',
            date: new Date(2014, 12, 15, 12, 30, 0),
            likes: 3,
            websiteUrl: 'http://pesho.com/'
            }
            ]
        }
    ];
    $scope.videos = videos;
    console.log(videos);});
```

And in the view i do this:

```
<div ng-controller="videoDisplayCtrl">
    <h2 ng-repeat="x in videos">
        {{x.comments[0].username}}
    </h2>
</div>
```

This will display only the first "username" of the first object of the "comments" array. I am missing something but i can't see what.

Comment: you want to display all username? just remove the index.

Comment: Wont work i have done this and receive error mesage:

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ']' not a primary expression at column 12 of the expression [x.comments[].username] starting at [].username].

Comment: try the solution I gave and let me know of any issues

Comment: Can you please mark an answer as correct so that it helps others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="videoDisplayCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="x in videos">
         <h2 ng-repeat="comment in x.comments">
        {{comment.username}}
         </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

You would need two loops, on to loop through your videos and the second to loop through your comments in each video which is another array.

Comment: Thx alot some minor change tho only on inner loop is h2 on outer i will change it to div and it works!!

Comment: yeah. sorry, kept the outer loop as h2 too.

Comment: :D its fine. @ArtemPetrosian I posted 6 minutes before you :P

Comment: you edited after me to fix layout problems, doesn't matter anyway :)

Comment: yup, doesn't really matter :)

Comment: ok, I've given you a plus, but I would say it is better to pick more readable variable name, instead of 'y'

Comment: dont say everybody copied his answer, I had created a fiddle for you as well which took sometime to post the answer. just 1min gap.

Comment: as I said before it doesn't matter who answer first, the quality of answer matter

Answer (score 0):

that is because you're displaying only the [0]th element.
remove it!

```
<h2 ng-repeat="x in videos">
    <div ng-repeat="y in x.comments"> 
         {{y.username}}
     </div>    
</h2>
```

UPDATED:

working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nomesh/u9d5apbz/3/)

Comment: No this is not the problem it still wont display usernames :(

Answer (score 0):

Your comments are also inside `Array`, so you need one more `ng-repeat` to display it:

```
<div ng-controller="videoDisplayCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="video in videos">
        <h2 ng-repeat="comment in video.comments">{{comment.username}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Btw, it is a good practice to pick a readable names for your variables/properties, instead of something like `x`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it:

**1** - Delete the "[0]", that will let the ng-repeat get the data from the iteration of the array.

```
<div ng-controller="videoDisplayCtrl">
   <h2 ng-repeat="x in videos">
       {{x.comments.username}}
   </h2>
</div>
```

**2** - Assign to "x" the array in the ng-repeat declaration

```
<div ng-controller="videoDisplayCtrl">
    <h2 ng-repeat="x in videos.comments">
        {{x.username}}
    </h2>
</div>
```